Joomla Componente Problem - An error has occurred. 404 Component not found
I dont get the component for the backend to work. Installing the component works fine without porblems. But If I click under "Reset Counter" in the Components Menu there is a error: "An error has occurred. 404 Component not found.". Instead there sould be the reset button there.
For school I should programm a Joomla Component that have a counter number and a add button in the Frontent, which counts the number +1 if you click the "add" button.
In the Backend under "Components" there should be a Menu "ResetCounter" and if I click on it there should be a Button named "Reset" where I can reset the number in the frontend back to 0.
I try to make a module for the frontend and a componente for the backend.
The module for the frontend with the counter works fine. But the backend conponent does not work.
Maybe someone can help. I think my problem could be the xml file.
I use Joomla 5.1.
Here is my module and component for the counter: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uRBAHrq6RvSP7tWw9q7sqaD5dbGABTXn?usp=sharing
Also my teacher said in Joomla there is a way to make a component with the frontend module inside. But I dont figure that out. I always make a module for the frontent and a component for the backend.

this question needs a lot more information unless you expect someone to download your component and see what's wrong (in the latter case, you are on the wrong site). At least specify what the ResetCounter is invoking, how you implemented its verb in the controller / model of the backend, and the exact error you are seeing. Modules and components are quite different, of course you can have frontend component views, choosing an approach just depends on your requirements.
